# Strange behavior in writing to file

Tags: java, file-io, io, printwriter, bufferedwriter

I was trying some basic Java I/O operations, I try to run the below code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File file = new File("fileWrite2.txt"); // create a File object
      try {
    FileWriter fr = new FileWriter(file);
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(file); // create a PrintWriter that will send its output to a Writer
    BufferedWriter br =  new BufferedWriter(fr);
    br.write("sdsadasdsa");br.flush();br.append("fffff");br.flush();
    pw.println("howdy"); // write the data
    pw.println("folks");
    pw.flush();
    pw.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When I run the above I get the following output in the file created :

```
howdy
folks
f
```

Can anyone explain why the 'f' is coming in the last line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are writing  15 characters on the `bufferedwriter` by doing this
`

```
br.write("sdsadasdsa");
br.flush();
br.append("fffff");`
```

But when you are writng on printWriter, it overwrites the content of the file 
this time you are writing

```
pw.println("howdy"); // write the data
pw.println("folks");
```

which is 10 characters only with two new line `\n` which takes 2 bytes since we use println because `\n` in windows will transform to `\r\n` . So total of 14.
so 1 character remains there which is f

Answer (score 7):

The `f` comes from the left over string of `br.append("fffff");` which was written in the file by the `BufferedWriter`.

Since both `BufferedWriter` and `PrintWriter` write to the same file, the contents written by the `PrintWriter` overwrite the contents written by the `BufferedWriter`.

But seems the no. of bytes written by `PrintWriter` fall short by 1 to completely overwrite the data written by `BufferedWriter` and thus you get the `f`.

If you change this `br.append("fffff");` to `br.append("ffffg");`, you can see that the `g` is now left over. Alternatively, changing `pw.println("folks");` to `pw.println("folks1");` will show that the previously written data is now completely overwritten by the `PrintWriter`.

All this confusion is because of having 2 different writers for the same file object which is the cause of the problem. As [@Boris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19971665/strange-behavior-in-writing-to-file/19971822#comment29729685_19971822) pointed out, have just 1 writer for a file object.

Note: Another interesting thing to test out would be to move the second `br.flush();` after the `pw.flush();`.

```
// br.flush(); // moved from here
pw.println("howdy"); // write the data
pw.println("folks");
pw.flush();
br.flush(); // to here
```

Comment: In short, only ever use one `Writer` per file.

Comment: Thanks. Updated the answer to mention that! :)

Comment: @R.J - Tried your suggestion and moved second br.flush(); after the pw.flush();. The output now changes to : **howdy
folfffff** can anyone plz explain this ? Do the Writers only write to file after we flush() the streams?

Answer (score 2):

In your code the following steps are executed.

1 When

```
br.write("sdsadasdsa");br.flush();br.append("fffff");br.flush();
```

is executed.

The file content will be

```
sdsadasdsafffff
```

2 when 
     pw.println("howdy");  is calling.

String **howdy** override the first 5 character **sdsad** and a new line terminates the line. In txt, 2 characters are needed **\r\n**, this will over write another 2 character .Then the file content will be as follows:

```
howdy

dsafffff
```

3 when 
    pw.println("folks");
is executed.

Since it is not called flush() method in step#2. String **folks** will over write the second line content in file. and a new line to over write another 2 characters.

Then the following content will be stored in file:

```
howdy

folks

f
```